# Plot histogram where x axis of the plot is a date

Tags: matlab

I know how to make a plot, but the data would be better represented as a histogram, Is there anyway I can easily convert this to a histogram?

```
figure();
plot(two_weeks,xAxis);
```

This is a datetime data type

```
disp(two_weeks)

21-Nov-2018 00:00:00   22-Nov-2018 00:00:00   23-Nov-2018 00:00:00   24-Nov-2018 00:00:00   25-Nov-2018 00:00:00   26-Nov-2018 00:00:00   27-Nov-2018 00:00:00   28-Nov-2018 00:00:00

Columns 9 through 14

29-Nov-2018 00:00:00   30-Nov-2018 00:00:00   01-Dec-2018 00:00:00   02-Dec-2018 00:00:00   03-Dec-2018 00:00:00   04-Dec-2018 00:00:00
```

---

```
disp(xAxis) = 

5
12
 1
 7
13
24
 2
27
62
 0
 3
17
74
 4
```

[image: Histogram plot]

Again I want something to look like this plot, except that it would be a histogram, I've tried looking through the histogram documentation and the MatLab helper form, but nothing answers my question, or helps me make the histogram in the desired way

Comment: Are you looking for the function `bar`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Idk, I'll check it out

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yeah, that's what I'm looking for, but the guy I'm working with specifically said he wanted a histogram, is there any difference? or could this have just been a miscommunication?

Comment: A histogram is where you count the number of times each element occurs. It is typically plotted with `bar`, but the histogram is a statistical technique that can be used without plotting at all. It seems to me that your data is a count of occurrences per date (i.e. it is a histogram). I guess you just need to plot it using `bar` to make it look like a histogram. But this is just a guess, I have no idea what data this is, how it was collected.